# list bounded queues in amqp

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

Is there any library in node.js that has implemented rabbitmq features comprehensively?
I've used amqplib in our project but it seems it has no feature to list bounded queues.
How can I list those queues in preferably amqplib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is implemented in amqplib or not, but you always have access to the management api, which with a greater chance can satisfy your need

here's what you need

```
curl -XGET https://user:pass@host/api/exchanges/{vhost}/{exchange_name}/bindings/source
```

here you can see complete list of features
https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.8.9/priv/www/api/index.html